# Error with include files when trying to compile HDF4 program

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors, include-path, hdf

I'm trying to compile a program that uses the HDF4 libraries. I installed HDF4 on my computer in /usr/local/ and I have confirmed that all of the necessary scripts, include files and libraries have been installed and that all environment variables are set correctly. I created a Makefile that compiles my two C files into object files and then links them together. When I compile the first C file, "readHDFfuncs.c", the compiler tells me that all of the HDF4 functions being called have not been declared. This should not be happening because my h4cc compiler is correctly including the proper directory.

I set the h4cc commands to -echo and have traced the compilation execution. Everything seems to be correct, however for some reason the function declarations are not getting through. h4cc is a gcc wrapper, its primary function is to handle include paths.

I have created a github to show you the files.

https://github.com/LandonClipp/HDFhelp/tree/master

Included is the output of my make command (which, remember, includes the -echo option for h4cc), the Makefile itself, my two C files, a header file, and the contents of my include directory. I really hate dropping all of this on people and asking for a solution but I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point out anything they see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried prepending `-I` onto the file paths in your makefile? This is necessary when importing directories. Though there could be other issues too.

So the second and third lines in your makefile would become:

```
INCLUDE=-I/usr/local/hdf-4.2.12/hdf4/include
LIB=-I/usr/local/hdf4.2.12/hdf4/lib
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors for documentation.